# Update Order of Existing Object Using SQLAlchemy OrderingList

Tags: python, mysql, orm, sqlalchemy

I am trying to update the order of an existing object when using the SQLAlchemy Ordering List.  Here's the example model used in the SQLAlchemy [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/orderinglist.html):

```
class Slide(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'slide'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    bullets = relationship("Bullet", order_by="Bullet.position",
                            collection_class=ordering_list('position'))

class Bullet(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bullet'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    slide_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('slide.id'))
    position = Column(Integer)
    text = Column(String)
```

I understand how to call `append()` with new objects and that works fine.

But how do I update the order of an existing object?

I have tried this and get some hard to understand results.

```
existing_item = session.query(Bullet).filter(Bullet.id == bullet_id).one()
slide.bullets.insert(new_order, existing_item)
slide.bullets.reorder()
session.commit()
```

There doesn't seem to be any documentation that explains how to update an existing object.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured this out.  I needed to call `remove()` on the object in question before re-inserting it.

Not sure if there's a better way, but this works.

```
existing_item = session.query(Bullet).filter(Bullet.id == bullet_id).one()
slide.bullets.remove(existing_item)
slide.bullets.insert(new_order, existing_item)
slide.bullets.reorder()
session.commit()
```

Also worth noting:  I am using `count_from=1` so that requires that I subtract 1 from `new_order` so that the end-user isn't confused by an order that starts at 0.

Comment: I was reordering existing objects and then setting them wholesale with `slide.bullets = reorderd_bullets`, and the new order was being discarded as soon as I called `commit()`. Calling `reorder()` before `commit()` solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I encountered an issue where using `remove(existing_item)` would remove the first item in `slide.bullets`. I'm not certain why this occurs but one possible culprit is that I use dataclass to define my models. However, I have worked around this by utilizing `pop(existing_item.position)` to remove the item from the list.